# UserScript can't find elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I have this simple user script meant to change some links on a YouTube page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           name
// @description    description
// @include        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @match          https://www.youtube.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("vm-video-title-content");

for (var i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
    titles[i].setAttribute("href", titles[i].getAttribute("href").replace("/edit?o=U&video_id", "watch?v"));
}
```

The code works when I use it in a bookmarklet or just paste it into console but seems to have no effect in Chrome installed as a user script.

I have tried using `window.onload` and `window.addEventListener()` to make the code run after the page is loaded but it didn't help to make the code work.

How to make this code work inside a user script?

Comment: Try, for interest sake, throwing the whole thing inside a `setTimeout`. I've found race conditions a common problem when doing userscripts... Give it something generous to start with (a second or so)

Comment: Please add part of html code that contain vm-video-title-content class to your question

Comment: Please also show how you're calling this script and the user script inside your html.

Comment: @shadow While that may solve the problem, it's almost never a good practice to solve problems with asynchronous code using timers.

Comment: Please refrain from commenting if you're not familiar with how userscripts work. More info here ~ http://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info

Comment: @4castle - granted it is rarely a good practice - but for debugging it's very useful. And given this is just a userscript, I don't think it really matters...

Comment: [// @run-at](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) - this is greasemonkey documentation, bu tampermonkey uses the same concept in the meta block - here's the [tampermonkey docs](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) for run-at

Comment: @shadow It indeed does work when I just wrap the code in `setTimeout`. Any suggestion for a value that's not unnecessarily big but will ensure the code will be executed?

Comment: @user7881662 No! As indicated by @4castle and @shadow, this is only appropriate for debugging. In order for your code to work reliably, you need to figure out what event needs to happen before your code should run, and then how to listen for that specific event. If your code depends on DOM elements that are inserted asynchronously after the page has loaded... that's not gonna be fun. But it's possible with something like [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 3):

Using the metablock [@run-at](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) attribute allows you to decide **when** to inject (and therefore run) the code

As you need to wait for the DOM to finish loading, you would use

```
// @run-at document-end
```

but, as this seems to be the default, perhaps you need

```
// @run-at document-idle
```

If the code relies on "dynamic" content, being loaded, however - you may well be out of luck and have to either watch for changes in DOM (using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver))

In this case, you'll want to inject your script as early as possible - maybe even

```
// @run-at document-start
```

setTimeout should be the very last resort, if ever!!

Comment: Hey, I would like to know from where you learnt JavaScript . (not sarcastic)

Comment: I learnt javascript by osmosis mainly (silly answer, but the truth is I never learned javascript formally - I just do it)

Comment: Does `@run-at` work outside of Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey? I don't use any userscript manager, just install userscripts on `chrome://extensions`. I also intend to share this userscript with other people and would like to avoid telling them "you need to install this other extension for it to work", especially for such a simple code.

Comment: I don't know @user7881662 - have you tried? (I don't use chrome much, I use tampermonkey for Firefox)

Comment: looking at [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) - *In Chromium/Google Chrome, Greasemonkey scripts are injected by default at a new point called "document-idle"* - this suggests even this answer is not going to help, as document-idle is the LATEST point at which to inject a script - and I fear using `MutationObserver` with a script added so late *may* be problematic

Comment: I did try all the values you mentioned, none of them seems to help. Using `@run-at document-body` results in `Invalid script header` error when I try to install the userscript so I assume the other values are recognized as correct by Chrome.